# Accessing a list of preferenceFragment views

Tags: android, android-fragments, robolectric, preferenceactivity

I am attempting to assert that the correct Preferences are being initialized when my Settings app's `onCreate()` method is called. I am trying to do this using the `robolectric` API.

Say I can reference an `ActivityController` - called `activityCont` and I also have a reference to the activity itself - called `myActivity`, obtained using `activityCont.get()`). I also have a reference to a `FragmentManager` called `fragMgr`. So my setup is:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
activityCont = Robolectric.buildActivity(mySettings.class);
myActivity = activityCont.get();
activityCont.create();
FragMgr = myActivity.getFragmentManager();
}
```

First I want to assert that certain fragments are being built. So for that I use:

```
@Test
public void canBuildParticularFragment() {
activityCont.attach().start().resume();
Assert.assertNotNull(FragMgr.findFragmentByTag((new myFragmentClass()).getTag()))
}
```

However, this test always fails, even though I can attest to the fact that myFragmentClass IS being built. Am I simply setting the activity to be in the wrong lifecycle stage? At which stage are fragments created so they can be accessible?

My other suspicion is that `getTag()` simply gets a tag specific to that instance of the class, which would mean the tag I "`get()`" in the above code would not return any fragments since it's different. If this is true, how would I get the correct fragment, since I don't know its tag, and I'd prefer not giving it an id in the xml file that contains it?

Lastly, I want to be able to, once I have a reference to the fragment, to `get()` a list of the `preferences` being displayed so I can `assert` they are correct based on some other configurations. So, how can I get the correct instance of the `myFragmentClass` `preferenceFragment`, and how can I get a list of its `preferences`?

Comment: Show the code of your activity. Do you put fragment with tag during fragment transaction?

Comment: Ah, also don't forget to call `executePendingTransactions()` on fragment manager

Comment: I thought the code for this would be hidden since it is handled by the PreferenceActivity class. This could be wrong.

Comment: Ah, ok. Why do you think that preference activity adds the fragments with tag? I took a look into source of it at don't see any tags there. They just replace fragment